# Google Sheets Script for Live Sorting with Multiple tables on a sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I found part of the following script online for Sorting alphabetically within a table when I add new content. The script sorts the relevant column and keeps the adjacent columns aligned with it.

The issue I have, however, is that this only appears to work for one area of content within my sheet. I copied and modified the script to hopefully work in two tables on the same sheet but only the second appears to be functioning. Can't seem to find what I'm overlooking. TIA for any help!

```
 /**
 * Automatically sorts the Nth column (not the header row) Ascending.
 */
function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 4;
  var tableRange = "B4:F31"; // Area to sort.
  var columnToSortNext = 3;

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
    range.sort( [{ column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true }, {column: columnToSortNext, ascending: true}] );
  }
}

 /**
 * Automatically sorts the Nth column (not the header row) Ascending.
 */
function onEdit(event2){
  var sheet2 = event2.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell2 = sheet2.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy2 = 9;
  var tableRange2 = "H4:J31"; // What to sort.
  var columnToSortNext2 = 8;

  if(editedCell2.getColumn() == columnToSortBy2){   
    var range2 = sheet2.getRange(tableRange2);
    range2.sort( [{ column : columnToSortBy2, ascending: true }, {column: columnToSortNext2, ascending: true}] );
  }
}
```

The code was originally written for one instance of sorting. My modified version with two active areas/tables doesn't like to work in both areas. The "2" side appears to work fine. The first half of the code does not. Maybe an issue with duplicated variables? Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a link to a test sheet with the functions?

Comment: Did you actually place two `onEdit()` functions in your script? If I understood properly, anytime a a cell is edited you want to sort both the tables.

Comment: You are overwriting one onEdit with the other, you need to give them different names or write a generic sorter and have the onEdit call it twice

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two onEdits. You can call other functions from the one onEdit, or you can combine like this and use if else:

```
function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 4;
  var columnToSortBy2 = 9;

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
    var tableRange = "B4:F31"; // Area to sort.
    var columnToSortNext = 3;
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
    range.sort( [{ column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true }, {column: columnToSortNext, ascending: true}] );
  } 
  else if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy2){  
    var tableRange2 = "H4:J31"; // What to sort.
    var columnToSortNext2 = 8;
    var range2 = sheet.getRange(tableRange2);
    range2.sort( [{ column : columnToSortBy2, ascending: true }, {column: columnToSortNext2, ascending: true}] ); 
  }
    else{
      return
  }}
```